# Changing size of div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a newbie to jQuery and need to change the class of the parent div.
When the user clicks on "**Toggle** **Class**" button, the class of the parent div changes from "**col-md-8**" to "**col-md-4**" and the height attribute of the image changes from "**500**" to "**300**". Can anyone suggest me a solution to this problem.
My html code is

```
<div class="col-md-8">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">
             <strong>Image</strong>
             <button class="btn btn-default" style="float:right;">Toggle Class</button>
          </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          <img class="img-responsive" height="500" src="http://lorempixel.com/750/500/" />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide some jquery and css you have tried! You will get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added the `class='img-responsive'` inside your image element. This is a Bootstrap class which **converts** your image into a responsive one.

It means that will ***resize itself*** as you ***resize its parent div***.

Bootstrap responsive images: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/#responsive-images

To change the parent div, add an `id='parent'` to the div and an `id='toggle'` for your button. Also, in your button, instead of `style='float:right'` you can add a class called `pull-right`. It's the same thing.

```
<div class="col-md-8" id='parent' >
     <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">
             <strong>Image</strong>
             <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" 
                id='toggle'>Toggle Class</button>
         </div>

         <div class="panel-body" style=''>
             <img class="img-responsive" height='500' 
                 src="http://lorempixel.com/750/500/" />
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#toggle').on('click',function(){
       $('#parent').toggleClass('col-md-4');
   });
});
```

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, the code you need is:

```
var $div = $('#div');
var $img = $('#img');

$('button').on('click', function() {
    if ($div.hasClass('col-md-8')) {
        $div.removeClass('col-md-8');
        $div.addClass('col-md-4');
        $img.attr('height', 300);
    } else {
        $div.removeClass('col-md-4');
        $div.addClass('col-md-8');
        $img.attr('height', 500);
    }
});
```

- Add `div` ID to your div, and `img` ID to your image (or target them by the class or tag name).